# Creating thumbnails

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I know questions about thumbnails have been asked in the past but I can't seem to find an answer that fits exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have a Model that has one ImageField with a related ModelForm. When submitting this form, I would like to create several different thumbnails for this image (giving them unique names that I have in mind so I can call them later in my templates) and save the original as well. How do I go about doing that?

I'm using PIL and will be doing some custom image manipulation so using a library that simply creates thumbnails won't be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions for sorl and easy_thumbnail but there's way too much magic going on there in my opinion that I just don't understand. I would love to do all this myself. Any tips on that?

Comment: Then skip easy_thumbnails and use Pil and Celery directly. If Celery is too magical as well you should process you images in the save method of you form or use a post_save-signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [easy-thumbnail's low level API](http://packages.python.org/easy-thumbnails/usage.html#python) to create the thumbnails:
 [`easy-thumbnails`](http://packages.python.org/easy-thumbnails/index.html) comes with some image processors builtin, but you can also add [custom procressors](http://packages.python.org/easy-thumbnails/ref/processors.html) and wrap the PIL operations you need.

For processing several images in the backgound you should consider using a task queue like [`celery`](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use sorl.thumbnail to generate your thumbnails **in template** like this:

```
{% thumbnail item.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

It's better than generating `on save` in many different ways:

- you can move to new server without moving thumbnails (sorl.thumbnail will regenerate them)
- you can easy change thumbnail size (just change parameters in template and it will magically happen)
- thumbnail size is saved where it should be (in the template)
- you can have different sizes in different templates (ie. mobile template)
- etc.

http://thumbnail.sorl.net/